# How to access ctx, request, and response objects inside a callback function in a route handler?

Tags: callback, promise, koa

How to access `ctx`, `request`, and `response` objects inside a callback function in a route handler of a async function call for example of a db query, without `yield`ing? In below two alternatives `this.body`cannot be assigned to `data`. koa.js used in the examples here. Inside route handlers is a db query, async with a callback.

I get an error koa.js complaining like *cannot set headers after they have been set*, which I understand Monsieur Koa has set already. That is quite acceptable when user does not provide them explicitly they prefer to set them to acceptable defaults and send `http response` rather than throw an error.

But I cannot set my headers after my async operations are completed.

Alternatives:

**1.** Carrying `this`via a variable inside the callback functions

```
publicRouter.get('/to1', function (next){
    var self = this;
    db.query('select username from users where username=${username}', {username:'isik'})
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            self.body = data;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
});
```

**2.** Using arrow callback functions to have `this` not bound to arrow functions' `this`:

```
publicRouter.get('/to1', function (next){
    db.query('select username from users where username=${username}', {username:'isik'})
        .then( data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.body = data;
        })
        .catch( error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
});
```

To clariy, with `yield` it works, which is not what I am asking here.

```
publicRouter.get('/to2', function* (next){
    var data = yield db.query('select username from users where username=${username}', {username:'isik'});
    if(data.length == 0){
        console.log("no data:", data);
        this.body = data;
    } else {
        console.log(data);
        this.body = data;
    }
});
```

Comment: I do not follow. What is going on exactly? Are you entering the `catch` function? `data` won't show correctly?

Comment: yes, https://jsfiddle.net/isikfsc/x0rL83hr/, `this.body` cannot be assigned to data.

Comment: I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" error in this fiddle.

Comment: where do you run the code, i have fiddled it just to be visible.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you've shared the fiddle so others could see the problem.

Comment: You answered "yes", but to which quiestion I asked?

Comment: maybe this was not the correct way to share server side code, sorry.

Comment: yes, I enter the catch() function.

Comment: And what is the error shown?

Comment: no jwt token is supplied. something like that.

Comment: So I think your problem has nothing to do with promises at all. Which function requires this jwt token?

Comment: sorry I am confused that was another issue, I am having difficulties in jwt authentication of my urls. The error here was something like, Can't set headers after they have already been sent (have been set). Koa.js sets them before I set them in callbacks.

Comment: But what do your server console shows?

Comment: The message above was the thing logged to console `Can't set body after they have been set`, like that. it is koa related i suppose.

Comment: it was this exactly `throw new Error('Can\'t remove headers after they are sent.');`

Comment: So, the generator version works properly as you say? Just to be clear, does `db.query` also returns a generator?

Comment: it returns a promise I think. and I can yield to it, the generator version works. And actually I use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can opt out of Koa's built-in response handling with `this.respond = false` which allows you to write and send the response in the same way you'd do it in Express.

Docs: https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/api/context.md#ctxrespond

Otherwise, you have to use `yield`. It's precisely what parks a handler until some async logic has run.

FWIW, it's almost always superior to wrap your callback-based async logic in a promise and then yield it in your route. I've yet to encounter a use-case for `this.respond = false`.